# Display on Windows 10 Pro won't sleep

Tags: windows-10, display, power-management

I have a Windows 10 Pro machine (self built) where the display never sleeps. I can force it to sleep with a variety of tools or mapping power button to display sleep etc but the display turns back on within 2 seconds every single time. It has been like this since new (several years) and I am getting VERY desperate here.

Things I have tried:

- Normal power settings (15min display sleep)
- Advanced power settings

  - Sleep - Allow wake timers: Disabled
  - USB - Selective suspend: Disabled
  - PCI - Link state PM: Off
  - Display - turn off after 15min
  - Multimedia - Sharing media - Allow computer to sleep
- Screen save: None
- Remote desktop: Off
- Turning ALL notifications Off
- Quitting all software
- Disconnect all USB devices except mouse (Razer and Logitech tested) and keyboard (Dell and Logitech tested)
- Leaving computer in login screen after reboot
- No AV
- No themes used, ever
- Event logs show nothing
- No Group Policy applied

Powercfg troubleshooting right after trying to sleep display & wakeup:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
None.

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
None.

PERFBOOST:
None.

ACTIVELOCKSCREEN:
None.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /lastwake
Wake History Count - 0
```

Hardware is today MSI Tomahawk Max + Ryzen 5 3600 + RTX 3080 + NVMe disk, no spinning rust, no external drives. Display is a 5120x1440 Samsung 49" on DP but I've tried others without success. Also had RTX 2060 earlier.

Any and all tips welcome.

Comment: Have you checked Task Scheduler [`taskschd.msc`] to see if any tasks are preventing sleep?

Comment: @JW0914 showing 136 active tasks, the ones running are CacheTask, ResolutionHost and SystemSoundsService. Not sure how to find one that might be preventing display sleep in this haystack?

Comment: Right-click on `Task Scheduler Library` → _Display All Running Tasks_, end all tasks listed, then put the display to sleep _(you'll want to restart the PC at some point today to ensure any tasks ended that need to be running are restarted)_. If that doesn't resolve the issue, it's likely not a task that's causing the issue - have you tried reinstalling the graphics driver? _(those would be the two main issues I can think of)_

Comment: Run [powercfg -energy](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html) and publish online the generated HTML report file (Dropbox, OneDrive etc).

Comment: I have reinstalled the gfx drivers many many times over the years.. but just reinstalled latest nvidia game ready drivers (511.79).  Will try killing the tasks and running energy report later today.

Comment: @harrymc added energy report at https://www.dropbox.com/s/0q6mr6rxx7cnti9/energy-report.html?dl=0

Comment: @JW0914 killing all tasks didn't help...

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with the energy report - the keyboard and mouse don't sleep, but that's normal. It doesn't seem like there is a hardware problem here. I suggest to [boot into Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234), and if the problem disappears then it is probably with some installed product.

Comment: @harrymc safe mode didn't do it.. I am going to upgrade BIOS and go through settings there next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I never found out what the issue really was. In the end I upgraded my motherboard firmware/bios (original from 2019) and this upgrade gave me a TPM on the MB which had been blocking Win11 upgrade. So then in a "whatever" moment I upgraded to Windows 11 and now there no issues with display sleep.

Thank you everyone for the suggestions, hopefully they will help someone else.